# My SIOSocket get disconneted automatically when i locked my ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

See this code it automatic goes to onDisconnect event when i locked ipad.Wifi is also turned on while i locked my ipad so is there any solutions?

[SIOSocket socketWithHost: @"https://localHost:3003" response: ^(SIOSocket *socket)
     {
         _SocketIO = socket;
        _SocketIO.onConnect =^()
         {
             ISConnected = true;
             NSLog(@"connected");
            [manager Connected];

```
     };
     [_SocketIO on: @"res" callback: ^(SIOParameterArray *args)
      {
          if ([self.delegate isKindOfClass:[Playing class]])
          {

          }
          [self.delegate ResponcewithDict:[args objectAtIndex:0]];
      }];
     _SocketIO.onConnectError =^(NSDictionary *dict)
     {
         NSLog(@"connection error");
     };

     _SocketIO.onDisconnect=^()
     {
      // [((ViewController *)[AppDelegate sharedInstance].window.rootViewController) onDisconnect];
         ISConnected = false;
         NSLog(@"disconnect");
     };

     _SocketIO.onError=^(NSDictionary *dict)
     {
         NSLog(@"error");
         ISConnected = false;
     };

     _SocketIO.onReconnect=^(NSInteger i)
     {
         NSLog(@"reconn");
         ISConnected = true;
     };

     _SocketIO.onReconnectionError=^(NSDictionary *dict)
     {
         NSLog(@"RERconnection error");
         ISConnected = false;
     };

 }];
```

Comment: Apple will close the socket when your device is locked. I found this in my iPhone and I think it has the same logic in iPad.

Comment: Try to active suitable background mode of you app then try again .

Comment: i tried this but still not working.